# Django Debug "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, django, debugging, exception

I am working on a django project for a while and all over sudden the django's debug stopped working displaying the following exception instead of showing the traceback of the bug in my code.

This exception seems to be a problem in the debugger itself and has been discussed in several places indicating that it could be a problem with line breaks in Mac ([here](https://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/711bb08fa81c3d67/bb755bde3335fc32?lnk=gst&q=IndexError%3a+list+index+out+of+range&hl=en)) and a line mismatch in the stack and the code on the disk ([here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.django.user/109299)).

Interestingly though, this exception only occurs when there is an exception that is NOT due to a syntax error. If I randomly add incorrect syntax, django show the normal debug interface indicating "invalid syntax (views.py, line xyz)".

I am using Django 1.3, Python 2.7, Ubuntu 11.04. The project is a couple of thousand lines strong, so it would be hard to copy and paste it in here.

Did anybody stumble across this as well and knows what other factors can cause this and how to fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 283, in run
  self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
  return self.application(environ, start_response)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 273, in __call__
  response = self.get_response(request)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
  response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 203, in handle_uncaught_exception
  return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 59, in technical_500_response
  html = reporter.get_traceback_html()

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 114, in get_traceback_html
  frames = self.get_traceback_frames()

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 242, in get_traceback_frames
  pre_context_lineno, pre_context, context_line, post_context = self._get_lines_from_file(filename, lineno, 7, loader, module_name)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 223, in _get_lines_from_file
  context_line = source[lineno].strip('\n')

 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the solution to the problem but I found a way at least to get more informative tracebacks by just using a different debugger.

Go here: https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver

-do a pip install on the devserver

-a pip install of werkzeug

-add dev-server to your apps in settings.py

-start django with ./manage.py runserver --werkzeug